# Ruby on Rails - Display last x tweets from twitter feed

Tags: html, twitter, rubygems

Can someone provide a simple block of code that will enable me to display my last 5 tweets from my twitter account using the twitter gem.

Comment: Does it have to be using the twitter gem? It's pretty straight forward using the twitter widget builder.

Comment: Can you customise the twitter widget? as in CSS? and I would still like to do it this way, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter widget has only very limited customization. Here are the two best resources I found:

Very clear tutorial on how to get Oauth working and a super simple 5-tweet feed up in Rails:
http://www.synaptian.com/blog/posts/using-the-twitter-gem-in-your-rails-application

Javascript solution that bypasses Oauth and grabs the values of a Twitter feed widget you set up in your Twitter account:
http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.BYRbZafw.dpbs

I implemented the second one, since the first pulled in only the tweet text and linked all of it, which made for an almost unusable display. The second one offered almost the same level of customization that was available before Oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Code example.

Make a debug output of new_statuses.first.attributes to see what's available to be displayed.

Put this in a file under lib/ or maybe in a .../concern/ folder

```
require 'twitter'

def tweets_from(ids)
  new_statuses = tw_client.statuses(ids)
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
  retry
  new_statuses
end

def tw_client
  @tw_client_reused ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    configure_client(config)
  end
end

def configure_client(config)
  config.consumer_key        = "FAKEasdfajsdlfkjalsdfkjslf"
  config.consumer_secret     = "FAKEkjsdhflkjashdfljkashldfjhasldfjkhalskdjfhlaskjd"
  config.access_token        = "172348716239-e7lcs8e7cltw8e57vlts8e57l8457vlFAKE"
  config.access_token_secret = "FAKEls3o84c7ntle847tnlc3o84n7tlc8o47tlc3847lct38n74"
end
```